# Auto login script

Tags: powershell, automation

I am trying to fix a script that automatically opens a page in edge and logs in. i can get it to open the page but the script errors out without entering the login info or directing to the desired final destination. the internal server page uses j_username and j_password to id the location where the credentials are entered. Im fairly new to coding and would like help to understand what im doing wrong and what i could be doing better.

Here is the code:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'msedge.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible

start microsoft-edge:http://internal URL to company

$usernmae="user"

$password="password"

While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 5;}

$usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('j_username')
$usernamefield.value = $username

$passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('j_password')
$passwordfield.value = $password

$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('login-submit')
$Link.click()

{Start-Sleep -Seconds 10;}

start microsoft-edge:http://final destination internal URL to company

$ie.Quit()
```

Comment: You misspelled `$username` in `$usernmae="user"`. But that's probably not the issue. Try adding `Start-Sleep -Seconds 1` before your `while` loop. Some times it takes a second for the `busy` property to be initialized.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460324/powershell-crashes-on-navigatecomplete2-event-firing/49288318#49288318) has an idiom I use pretty frequently with browser automation: `Do {sleep 1} While ($ie.Busy)`

Comment: I will add that and let you know, username is misspelled as I removed the real one and put in that dummy.

Comment: @RichMoss have changed it to the 'Do {sleep 1} While ($ie.Busy)' code and no change. it still fails to enter the password and login. would it be possible to do a script call? like when the first scritp opens the page a second script enters the login info and calls a third script to lead to the final destination URL?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that the `$ie` object is not connected to the browser when you use `start microsoft-edge:http://internal URL to company`. Use the `Navigate` method:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'msedge.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible
$ie.Navigate("https://internal-login-page")
Do {sleep 1} While ($ie.Busy)
$usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('j_username')
$usernamefield.value = "user"
$passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('j_password')
$passwordfield.value = "password"
$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('login-submit')
$Link.click()
Do {sleep 1} While ($ie.Busy)
$ie.Navigate("https://final-page")
```

Comment: i will implement the recommendation and let you know how it goes

Comment: i have made the changes and the script fails out and nothing happens

Comment: How are you starting the script, and how does it 'fail out'? I've tested similar code with `$ie = New-Object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"` but not with `msedge.Application`. It's possible that the Edge browser doesn't support the same interface.

Comment: that is my thought. im running it 2 ways, 1st as a batch file and second as a powershell script. when i say fail out it opens the page but never inputs the login creds or redirects to the desired page after login. further it fails to wait and tries to excute everything at once so it produces errors about unexpected handling in reference to the username and password.

Comment: If you send the exact error text it would be helpful.